# BrightScript: How to create a grid of PosterGrid items?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am trying to develop a Roku app. Not able to create a grid of items where each item is a poster grid in itself.

Could not able to find any example for this situation? Link to any similar example will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [MarkupGrid](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/MarkupGrid) or [RowList](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/RowList) and set their "itemComponentName" field to [PosterGrid](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/PosterGrid). Not sure if there is any example of such app in the internet.